# Problem downloading .exe file from Amazon S3 with a signed URL in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, amazon-s3

I have a large collection of Windows exe files which are being stored/distributed using Amazon S3. We use signed URLs to control access to the files and this works great except in one case when trying to download a .exe file using Internet Explorer (version 8). It works just fine in Firefox. It also works fine if you don't use a signed URL (but that is not an option).

What happens is that the IE downloader changes the name from 'myfile.exe' to 'myfile[1]' and Windows no longer recognizes it as an executable. Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did some searching and looks like IE has a bunch of issues with handling downloaded files. Kinda sad really.

Comment: Yeah, so far the best thing I have seen is to add a .removeme option to the end of the filename which I'd rather not do.

Comment: Have you tried different Content-Type meta tags/file names that are unlikely to have been downloaded already?

Comment: Was John's link helpful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks like someone found a solution for this problem.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=108392) Apparently you need to send the proper content-type header.

THIS IS HOW YOU FIX IT

In A3 Click on your .exe file choose Actions and bring up properties

Choose Metata Data

Add more metadata

Choose Key: Content-Disposition   Value:  attachment

then type this after attachment; filename=yourfilename.exe